# How to remove or override css which is referred from different CSS files

Tags: jquery, css

I have a CSS class which comes from different files as mentioned in the following image:

[image]

I tried to override like the following

```
body .ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar
            {
                padding : 0.0em 0.1em 0.4em 0em !important;
            }
```

and tried to remove the css class from DOM like the following ,

```
$(document).load(function () {
             $( "div" ).odd().removeClass( "ui-dialog-titlebar" );
            });
```

But none of the above worked for me and I could not find the reason.

Is it possible to override or remove the class as I don't want to do anything in the CSS class they are referred since they will be used in other pages.

Comment: You need to make the selector of the rule that overrides more specific. As you can see in the image, the rules with higher specificity override the others. Do not use `!important` for this.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, Thanks for your input, could you please add some sample, i dont understand.

Comment: `body div.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar`

Comment: @CodeNotFound, I _strongly_ recommend that you take some time (when you have some time) to read up on CSS methodologies. My favourite is (a slightly modified version of) _BEM_. There are other methodologies (_OOCSS_, _SMACSS_ etc. but they all have the same goal: ensuring your CSS remains manageable and extendable now and in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to add a custom class to it and place there the padding settings you need (with or without !important). You can place that css in your component part